# How to make only the form size to change when changing its size in the designer?

Tags: c#, winforms

now when i change the form size in the designer by dragging it at the bottom the other controls move with it down. i want to make more space at the bottom to add more controls.

this screenshot is the original size :

[image: original size]

and this screenshot when i drag and change the form size at the bottom :

[image: after changed the form size there is no space at the bottom the controls moved with the form size.]

Comment: Then don't dock/AnchorStyles.Bottom the controls ? Use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to lay out your controls.

Comment: Although I opt to vote to close @rojer - you should explain your actual question (I think it's lost in translation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove bottom anchor from controls you don't want to resize.

This guy:

[image]